# IntersectionObserver is lagging behind intersection

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on setting up a text animation triggered when an element becomes visible.  I am using an IntersectionObserver to trigger the animation.

The problem I am having is on mobile, if I scroll to a div quickly the animation event doesn't trigger right away. There is a small lag.

Can see here on mobile: https://main.d3ds1uhq2xz2ld.amplifyapp.com/

My functions are:

```
export function scrollAnimation(selector, options = {}) {
  let component = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  component = Array.from(component);
  component.forEach((comp) => {
    addObserver(comp, options);
    // comp.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
    //   comp.classList.remove("active");
    // });
  });
}

function addObserver(comp, options) {
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.classList.add("active");
        // observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      } else {
        // setTimeout(() => {
        entry.target.classList.remove("active");
        // }, "250");
      }
    });
  }, options);
  observer.observe(comp);
}
```

and I am calling the `scrollAnimation` in my index.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollAnimation(".animate", {
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 0,
    });
    const isVerified = localStorage.getItem("isVerified");
    setIsAgeVerifyModal(!isVerified);
  }, [location]);
```

The css uses keyframes

```
.active {
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

  @keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Working on a JS Fiddle, but it looks like keyframes are not compatible.

Comment: Please try to make a runnable snippet actually in your question. An external site may disappear or be debugged, rendering your question useless for future readers. Also note your site gives Unexpected Application Error!

Failed to construct 'IntersectionObserver': rootMargin must be specified in pixels or percent currently.

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks. I will try and get a working snippit up as soon as I can. For now that issue you saw is resolved.